# Ubiquity crash after booting up installation drive

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, ubiquity

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on an NEC computer. I downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 x64 ISO from the Ubuntu homepage. When I boot up Ubuntu using a USB drive, it showed ubiquity. But then, I can't click anything (the install button, the "try it out" button, anything); and then, after a few seconds, ubiquity will crash with an error: "ubiquity crashed with signal 7 in FT_Load_Glyph()"

How can I fix this?

Side Note: I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04(First installed Windows, now trying to install Ubuntu).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think that's not a question. Please could you rephrase your question to be a question?
And given it's a crash I'm not sure what you can do about it (if anything)...

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. I was using an sd-card(plus an sd-card to USB converter) to install Ubuntu, and that was the problem. Once I used a USB drive, it worked perfectly without any problems.